# How to devide or split strings in php with separator?

Tags: php, string, split

in PHP, how to split this strings, for example :

```
OBKFA4F26ORJI3ALFYI3QB4ZN
```

into:

```
OBKFA-4F26O-RJI3A-LFYI3-QB4ZN
```

Comment: http://php.net/split (with a regex based on number of characters)

Comment: Short question deserves short answer... 
https://www.google.de/search?q=php+split+strings

Comment: `str_split()` every 5 characters, then `implode()` with a `-` separator: `echo implode('-', str_split('OBKFA4F26ORJI3ALFYI3QB4ZN', 5));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
<?php
$string = "OBKFA4F26ORJI3ALFYI3QB4ZN";
    $output = str_split($string, 5);
    echo implode("-",$output);
?>
```

Output:

> OBKFA-4F26O-RJI3A-LFYI3-QB4ZN

[ONLINE DEMO](http://codepad.org/FZ98eKP0)

Comment: @Romy Romaldus This may help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex and then replace the match with `-`

```
.{5}(?!$)\K
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/63)

OR

```
$re = "/.{5}(?!$)/m";
$str = "OBKFA4F26ORJI3ALFYI3QB4ZN";
$subst = "$0-";
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/67)